# Spring data mongo - unique random generated field

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring data mongo. I have a collection within a document that when I add an item to it I would like to assign a new automatically generated unique identifier to it e.g. (someGeneratedId)

```
@Document(collection = "questionnaire")
public class Questionnaire {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field("answers")
  private List<Answer> answers;
}

public class Answer {
  private String someGeneratedId;
  private String text;
}
```

I am aware I could use `UUID.randomUUID()` (wrapped in some kind of service) and set the value, I was just wondering if there was anything out of the box that can handle this? From [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/#mapping-usage) `@Id` seems to be specific to `_id` field in mongo:

> The @Id annotation tells the mapper which property you want to use for
> the MongoDB _id property

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no out of the box solution for generating ids for properties on embedded documents.

If you want to keep this away from your business-logic you could implement a `BeforeConvertCallback` which generates the id's for your embedded objects.

```
@Component
class BeforeConvertQuestionnaireCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<Questionnaire> {

    @Override
    public Questionnaire onBeforeConvert(@NonNull Questionnaire entity, @NonNull String collection) {
        for (var answer : entity.getAnswers()) {
            if (answer.getId() == null) {
                answer.setId(new ObjectId().toString());
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

You could also implement this in a more generic manner:

Create a new annotation:  `@AutogeneratedId`.
Then listen  to all `BeforeConvertCallback`'s of all entities and iterate through the properties with reflection. Each property annotated with the new annotation gets a unique id if null.